# How can I get grep to find a line in the file but also show the line following it?

Tags: grep

I want to use grep command to extract those lines in a text file which contain a special pattern but i also want to extract the next line of those specific lines. Is it possible using grep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify how many lines to print after a match With the `-A` option:

```
grep -A1 pattern file
```

Demo:

```
$ cat file
line one 
line two
line three

$ grep -A1 'one' file
line one 
line two
```

Next time `man grep`!

Comment: change the 1 to however many lines after the match you'd like to include.